# How to batch-edit pdfs to remove headers and footers

Tags: pdf, editors

I have a large number of .pdf files with much the same headers and footers that I’d like to remove.

Is there a something that can remove everything up to a known string and everything after a different known string leaving a valid .pdf?

Comment: Do you just want the text not to appear, or do you want it removed from the pdf as well?

Comment: I’m wanting to remove it - but making it invisible would work just as well. Do you have a way to do that?

Comment: I've not tried it, but `podofobox` from tools `podofo` can change the crop box, which determines what is visible. Beware, some tools may not preserve things like bookmarks.  Alternatively, you can use `pdf2ps` from ghostscript to convert to PostScript, and you may then be able to recognise the text to remove with `sed` etc. `ps2pdf` converts back to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [pdfedit](http://pdfedit.cz/en/index.html) (which being open source, can be found [here](https://github.com/nullishzero/PDFEdit)).

Didn't try this however, since it is only for Windows afaik.

The other way you could do this is by using OCR, and there a *lots* of different apps and ways to do this: [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) is one of them. (work on windows, mac and un*x)

*You need to add more detail to your post*, since it does not say what operating system it is targeted for, or ways you would want to do this (script, gui app, etc).